# Learning about functions in swift

Tags: swift

first time here. I'm watching a video to supplement my learning on Swift (It seems to be an older video that has to name the first var when called, which I understand is no longer the case). Anyway, I'm having a hard time understanding how line 7 is going wrong. It's saying that I can't have a function return an integer. It's a function within a function that returns a function with no arguments but returns an integer type). Thanks!

```
func buildIncrementor() -> () -> Int {
    var count = 0
    func incrementor() -> Int {
        count += 1 //video uses ++count//
        return count
    }
    return incrementor()
}
var incrementor = buildIncrementor()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
func buildIncrementor() -> () -> Int {
    var count = 0
    func incrementor() -> Int {
        count += 1 //video uses ++count//
        return count
    }
    return incrementor
}
var incrementor = buildIncrementor()
```

`incrementor()` returns the return value of the `incrementor()` function whereas `incrementor` returns the function.